# Assign a particular id for dataframe matching a regex pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

Need to assign a particular id for each dataframe matching the below conditions

```
fd = df[(df['B'].str.match('.*Color:.*') | df['B'].str.match('.*colorFUL:.*')) & df.A.isnull()]
fd2 = df[(df['B'].str.match('.*Type:.*')) & df.A.isnull()]
```

In the output file, both dataframes are getting written one below other. Need to add a column C where ID '1' is assigned to fd and ID '2' is assigned to fd2. This would be helpful in filtering the dataframes.

This is the current output

```
A   B
nan this has Color:Red
nan Color: Blue,red, green
nan Color: Yellow
nan This has many colors. Color: green, red, Yellow
nan Filter oil Type: Synthetic Motor oil
nan Oil Type : High Mileage Motor oil
```

Expected Output

```
A   B   C
nan this has Color:Red  1
nan Color: Blue,red, green  1
nan Color: Yellow   1
nan This has many colors. Color: green, red, Yellow 1
nan Filter oil Type: Synthetic Motor oil    2
nan Oil Type : High Mileage Motor oil   2
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: `Need to add a column C...` - what part are you having trouble with? What is the question? [https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html)

Comment: A column C to be added where a specific ID can be assigned for each dataframe (fd and fd2) so it can be filtered out using that ID

Comment: But what are you having trouble with? - adding a new column?, assigning a value based on a condition?, *constructing* the condition?

Comment: Adding a new column C and assigning ID '1' or '2' to that column based on the dataframe matching the regex..having trouble with this part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Adding a new column C and assigning ID '1' or '2' to that column based on the dataframe matching the regex.

```
In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
    A                                                B
0 NaN                               this has Color:Red
1 NaN                           Color: Blue,red, green
2 NaN                                    Color: Yellow
3 NaN  This has many colors. Color: green, red, Yellow
4 NaN             Filter oil Type: Synthetic Motor oil
5 NaN                Oil Type : High Mileage Motor oil
```

You constructed two conditions:

```
In [18]: one = (df['B'].str.match('.*Color:.*') | df['B'].str.match('.*colorFUL:.*')) & df.A.isnull()

In [19]: one
Out[19]: 
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool

In [20]: two = (df['B'].str.match('.*Type:.*')) & df.A.isnull()

In [21]: two
Out[21]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
dtype: bool
```

Here is one way to make a new column.

```
In [22]: df['C'] = 0
```

Use the boolean series of your conditions to assign values based on those conditions.

```
In [23]: df.loc[one,'C'] = 1

In [24]: df.loc[two,'C'] = 2

In [25]: df
Out[25]: 
    A                                                B  C
0 NaN                               this has Color:Red  1
1 NaN                           Color: Blue,red, green  1
2 NaN                                    Color: Yellow  1
3 NaN  This has many colors. Color: green, red, Yellow  1
4 NaN             Filter oil Type: Synthetic Motor oil  2
5 NaN                Oil Type : High Mileage Motor oil  0
```

---

> if df is the input dataframe and fd is the output dataframe matching the pattern, how to directly assign an id to fd without the boolean check

```
fd = df.loc[one]
fd['C'] = 1
```

Comment: only dataframes matching those patterns(Color: or Type:) is currently outputted..a separate boolean check wont be necessary.. if df is the input dataframe and fd is the output dataframe matching the pattern, how to directly assign an id to fd without the boolean check..

Comment: For example `fd = df[(df['B'].str.match('.*Color:.*') | df['B'].str.match('.*colorFUL:.*')) & df.A.isnull(),['id']='1']`...is this feasible

Comment: `fd = df.loc[one]   fd['C'] = 1` this is running perfect in the terminal but doesnt show in the output file.. `for i in range(len(fd)): writer.writerow([fd[col].values[i] for col in df.columns])`...how to integrate in this so it can be outputted in a separate file

Comment: Please do not morph a question when you find other problems after trying out answers or comments. Just ask a new question. Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: changed `for i in range(len(fd)): writer.writerow([fd[col].values[i] for col in df.columns])` to `for i in range(len(fd)): writer.writerow([fd[col].values[i] for col in fd.columns])`..it runs now..thanks a lot